# How do I extract a Collection from an ExecutionResult in Java?

Tags: java, collections, neo4j, cypher

Given the following query:

```
CREATE (versionNode:Version {previousVersions: [4,3,2,1]}) 
RETURN versionNode.previousVersions AS versions
```

how can I end up with a `Collection<Long>` from an `ExecutionResult`? AFAIK, the `Node#getProperty()` method can only return primitive types, so I cannot use that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. This code made me realize it:

```
String cypher = "CREATE (versionNode:Version {previousVersions: [4,3,2,1]}) " +
                "RETURN versionNode.previousVersions AS versions";
ExecutionResult result = new ExecutionEngine(db).execute(cypher);
System.out.println(result.iterator().next().get("versions").getClass());
```

this outputted the strange symbol:

```
class [J
```

According to the Java docs for [`Class#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) it means the type of the object returned is a primitive `long` array.

So now I can do this and get my numbers returned into a collection:

```
Collection<Long> versionsCollection = new ArrayList<>();
long[] versions = (long[]) result.iterator().next().get("versions");
for (long v : versions) {
  versionsCollection.add(v);
}
```